# External Content Type missing

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I successfully created and External Content Type in SharePoint Designer however on refresh it disappears. On creating a new one I then see my previously made ones however they will all disappear on save and refresh.

Message I am getting in my window:
'There are no external content types to show in this view that match the current filter settings. Remove or modify the filter settings to display more items'

I just with I knew where these 'filter settings' are.

I should mention these content types DO show up in the SharePoint environment itself just not in my designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
click 'Name' Column in what would be the list of content type and hit all. I had someone inadvertently set it to something different.