# External content type not visible

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type

I created external content type in my SharePoint 2013 site to get data from sql database. Now I want to change the connection but I cannot see my old external content types in the designer. Any idea about this.

Comment: You can refer to this - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161418/external-content-type-missing

Comment: @HabiburRahaman already gone through it. Filter is not a reason in my case.

Comment: please provide a screenshot about the External Content types section. And also check if your external content type exists in CA->Business Data Connectivity Service.

Comment: It comes blank, says nothing to show here. Yes I am able to see the external content types in the CA

Comment: if creating an external list/column, could you find the external content type in External Content Type Picker?